# Unable to make Dymo drivers on pi

Tags: raspbian, cups

When I try to make the Dymo drivers on my pi, make fails as per below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5 $ sudo make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src'
Making all in lw
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src/lw'
Making all in tests
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src/lw/tests'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src/lw/tests'
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pi/dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5/src/lw'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../common    -O2 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas   -MT raster2dymolw.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/raster2dymolw.Tpo -c -o raster2dymolw.o raster2dymolw.cpp
In file included from raster2dymolw.cpp:37:0:
../common/CupsFilter.h: In member function ‘int DymoPrinterDriver::CCupsFilter<D, DI, LM>::Run(int, char**)’:
../common/CupsFilter.h:135:10: warning: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     std::auto_ptr<CHalftoneFilter> H;
          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/memory:81:0,
                 from raster2dymolw.cpp:28:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:49:28: note: declared here
   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from raster2dymolw.cpp:37:0:
../common/CupsFilter.h: In member function ‘void DymoPrinterDriver::CCupsFilter<D, DI, LM>::InitDocument(const char*)’:
../common/CupsFilter.h:218:3: error: ‘ppd_file_t’ was not declared in this scope
   ppd_file_t* ppd = ppdOpenFile(getenv("PPD"));
   ^~~~~~~~~~
../common/CupsFilter.h:218:15: error: ‘ppd’ was not declared in this scope
   ppd_file_t* ppd = ppdOpenFile(getenv("PPD"));
               ^~~
../common/CupsFilter.h:218:46: error: there are no arguments to ‘ppdOpenFile’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘ppdOpenFile’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   ppd_file_t* ppd = ppdOpenFile(getenv("PPD"));
```

I've been trying for hours to get this to work but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I expect you were following some instructions.  Could you edit the question and include the instructions?

Comment: What version of C++ do you have and what version of C++ the code was written for?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be sent to Dymo (whatever they are) and not here?

Comment: You will get a faster response here (even if it takes months) than from Dymo.

Comment: Or, in this case, if it takes years to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there were some changes that happened with CUPS some time ago that required adding a few headers.  I found what to edit prowling around the ArchLinux dymo-cups-drivers package, but so you don't have to do that, I'll describe what to edit here.

These file paths are relative to the dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.x.x/ path where you untarred the sources.

- src/common/CupsFilter.h

After `#include <cups/raster.h>`, add a new line reading `#include <cups/ppd.h>`.

- src/lm/CupsFilterLabelManager.h

After `#include <cups/raster.h>`, add a new line reading `#include <cups/ppd.h>`.

- src/lw/CupsFilterLabelWriter.h

After `#include <cups/raster.h>`, add a new line reading `#include <cups/ppd.h>`.

- src/common/CupsPrintEnvironment.cpp

After `#include <cups/cups.h>`, add a new line reading `#include <cups/sidechannel.h>`

Once you've done this, you should be able to `./configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install` the sources.